# Bad word that will curse a family

Tags: word, phrase

## Background

**So my friend, who’s Chinese, cried a few weeks ago.**

Apparently, a boy(let’s call him Bobby) in our class said a ‘bad word that will curse a family and their generation forever’. I asked what it was but all she said was...

> Do you want me to curse your family? ***sniff***

And then broke down in tears.

If I was her, I would have just ignored it and laughed.

## Question

What is the word/phrase that Bobby used? Is it really bad?

Comment: Was it Mandarin / Cantonese or?  Did he actually say the word or he's just referencing it?

Comment: It may be 絕子絕孫.

Comment: @Alex it’s mandarin.

Comment: @hinen after a google search, 絕子絕孫 seems mainly used in Taiwan, and 断子绝孙 maybe the similar word in mainland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was Cantonese, it would obviously be 冚家剷 (entire family die)

Since it was Mandarin,  the only common phrases that curse someone's entire family I can think of are:

- 絕子絕孫 (no male descendants, the family line ends)
- 男盜女娼 (one's male descendants will be thieves and female descendants will be prostitutes)

Or it can be any cursing phrase with '你全家' before it. For example "你全家不得好死" (all of your family members will die a horrible death)

Comment: +1 for the Cantonese phrase. I know it is considered to be very insulting  indeed among all the Cantonese profanity that there are.

Comment: 'insulting'  is too mild a word for this cruse.  It is 'vicious'